# Firebase registration token is not showing in Android Studio logcat

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using the Android studio Arctic Fox version. I need to implement an automated notification app that is going to send notifications by date. I am running my apps on an actual device with the 6.0.1 android version. I have connected fcm and set up the dependencies as well. But token is not showing on logcat. Also registered the app in firebase. Any ideas why this is happening?

build:gradle(:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.f1"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

build:gradle(module)

```
  dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

manifest.xml

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s)
    {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        Log.d("My token", "Refreshed Token"+s);
        sendRegistrationToServer(s);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String s) {
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ran the app on the device before adding the `MyFirebaseMessagingService` code, it probably already generated a token then. Adding the `MyFirebaseMessagingService` does not generate a new token, so your  `onNewToken` will not be called.

The two options to get the token in that case are:

1. Call `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()` from (for example) you main activity and call the same `sendRegistrationToServer` there.
2. Delete the app and its data after you added the `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()` code, and reinstall the app. Deleting the data deletes the token, so then when you run the app it will generate a new token and call your `onNewToken`.

Comment: Yes I did try your method. When I put this statement android:stopWithTask="false" as service in my manifest, it worked. But I really don't know why that worked. Thank you for your response @Frank. :)